# C# - Как из функции, которая должна вернуть Task вернуть строку?

Tags: c#

Есть функция, которая работает только тогда, когда она возвращает `Task`

```
public static async Task Get(String url)
{
    HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    string str = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return str;
}
```

Но мне нужно вернуть строку. Как это сделать?

Answer (score -1):

Вкратце, если вам нужно быстро разобраться с этим и продолжить работать, условно представьте, что await **снимает** тип `Tas<>` и возвращает то, что **под ним**. Примеры:

- await Task -> int
- await Task -> string
- await Task<List> -> List
- await Task<List<GenericType>> -> List<GenericType>

А для изучения, вот список литературы:

- [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios)
- [Metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.3.php)
- [Habr](https://habr.com/ru/articles/470830/)

**UPD:**
Вообще тема асинхронности очень большая и очень глубокая, и не получится вкратце объяснить вам как это работает. Но вот основные критерии для создания асинхронного метода:

- Метод должен быть обозначен как `async`
- Метод должен возвращать `Task`, `Task<T>` или `void` (Не рекомендуется)
- В методе должны присутствовать вызовы других асинхронных методов (С использованием ключевого слова `await`)

Далее то, что уже описал выше. Для вызова асинхронного метода используйте `await`. По простому - `Task` это асинхронная задача, результат которой вы сможете получить только после её выполнения (Логично).

У вас в коде есть очень крутой пример, который достаточно легко понять. У вас идёт вызов `HttpClient.GetAsync()`. Этот метод возвращает вам наполнение страницы в формате html, который вы можете прочитать в виде строки. Почему там стоит `await` и что он значит вообще? `await` ожидает выполнения асинхронно задачи, т.е., полной загрузки страницы.

Для примера, у вас пропал интернет и вы хотите зайти на какой-то сайт (Через браузер), но вы не сможете этого сделать потому что у вас нет интернета. Вы будете просто ждать окончания загрузки страницы аналогично работе ключевого слова `await`. Пока сайт не загрузится, вы не сможете дальше делать работу на сайте.

Без ключевого слова `await` данный вызов будет выполняться в другом потоке. Аналогичный пример. Пока вы будете ожидать загрузки вашего сайта какой вы хотите посмотреть (Или загрузку игры, или её скачивание и т.д.) вы можете выполнять другие задачи:

- Зайти на другой сайт
- Зайти в другую игру
- Пойти покушать
- Пойти погулять (Если вы скачиваете 250 Гб)

А ваша задача решается этим кодом:

```
public static async Task<string> Get(String url)
{
    HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    return await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

**Что изменилось?**
Метод `ReadAsStringAsync();` возвращает `Task<string>`. Что бы вернуть строку из вашего метода, вам нужно через `await` убрать этот `Task` и указать, что ваш метод будет возвращать `Task<string>`.

Почему `Task<string>`, а не `string`? Потому что вызов асинхронного метода может быть только внутри другого асинхронного метода. А об этом я писал выше